# hsqldb eats almost 1GB RAM

Tags: debian, database, java

I run hsqldb Server in new empty folder on debian 5 by this:

```
java -cp hsqldb-2.0.0.jar org.hsqldb.Server&
```

and java with this process eats 908MB. Is it ok?

Comment: And this is wrong, how?

Answer (score 1):

By default HSQLDB tables are stored in memory, so yes this seems normal.